# Как запустить android-демона через adb

Tags: android-ndk, android-adb

Доброго времени суток, помогите пожалуйста решить проблему:

Есть android-демон написанный под Android NDK, простенький tcp сервер. Компилируется в .so либу и запускается на устройстве/эмуляторе в режиме демона.

Проблема заключается в запуске.

Если я захожу в shell:

```
adb shell
```

А затем пишу команду:

```
su -c /dir/daemon 55000
```

То все запускается и работает, но если я хочу сделать:

```
adb shell su -c /dir/daemon 55000
```

То команда выполняется, но никаких ошибок нет и демон не стартует.
Пробовал различные варианты с установкой кавычек одинарных и двойных. Если несколько раз заспамить данную команду в консоль, то в какой-то момент adb лочит консоль и затем демон таки запускается. Но хотелось бы чтобы результат был после первой попытки.

Мне надо запускать данный демон из Qt приложения. Делаю это через QProcess.

Не могу понять в чем причина такого поведения. Полазил в сорцах но ничего толкового не нашел.

Демон рабочий, если запустить руками то все работает как надо.
Ставил простенькое логирование в код демона сразу на входе в функцию main, но туда даже не попадаем если пытаемся запустить с консоли через

```
adb -s <dev_name> shell su -c /dir/daemon <port_number>
```

Пробовал генерировать shell-скрипт внутри Qt с номером порта и запускать таким образом:

```
adb -s <dev_name> shell sh /dir/script.sh
```

Результат тот же, работает только если предварительно зайти в adb shell

Update:
заметил что данная проблема присутствует только в случае когда нам надо запуститься в режиме демона, т.е. либо при помощи функции daemon() либо со знаком & в конце команды. В других случая все нормально запускается даже из консоли

Comment: а телефон точно рутованный? Что делает вывод `adb su` (меняется ли знак приглашения). Разрешено ли использовать рут права в `adb` (настройки разработчика, режим рута).

Comment: меняет, телефон рутованный, да и я на эмуляторе тестирую. Суть в том, что команды рабочие, если дергать напрямую из adb shell, а вот когда пытаешься с консоли ОС дернуть, то ничего не происходит, команда проходит, но в adb shell ps демона нет. 

Может сработать только если заспамить команду в консоль несколько раз. Такое ощущение что там то-ли таймауты какие-то стоят.

То-ли я идиот то-ли лыжи не едут

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне подсказали такое решение:

adb shell su -c "/dir  > /dev/null 2> /dev/null < /dev/null &"
Однако оно работает не на всех версиях api, скорее всего из-за различий в парсинге команд со стороны adb shell. Т.е. где-то нужны доп кавычки, где-то они мешают. Поэтому я стянул исходник тулзы nohup, добавил ее в свой проект ndk как executable lib и скомпилил под все архитектуры.

Теперь демона запускаю так:

```
shell su -c /data/local/tmp/start_daemon.sh
```

Сам код скрипта:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
/data/local/tmp/nohup 
/data/local/tmp/daemon <portn_number> &
```